# How can I display column headings in spark-sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

I'm running spark-sql under the Hortonworks HDP 2.6.4 Sandbox environment. I've created 2 very basic tables in spark-sql, a Customer table, and an Orders table. I've written a JOIN to collect order information as follows:

```
SELECT Customers.ID, Name, Product_Name
FROM Customers JOIN Orders
WHERE Customers.ID = Orders.Customer_ID;
```

However, unlike SQL code in pyspark, where column names appear as default, spark-sql has no column names showing as a default display. I get the below results (I have 5 customers and 5 orders in my database):

```
2222    Emily   HTC Edge
1111    John    Google Nexus 5
1111    John    Samsung Galaxy 7
1111    John    iphone 6
4444    Jane    Samsung J Series
Time taken: 0.516 seconds, Fetched 5 row(s)
spark-sql>
```

Anyone know how to turn column header names on, I would have liked to see ID, Name, and Product_Name as the first row in the result set?

Comment: what command are you using to display the results? df.show() does show column names in output.

Comment: He is using spark-sql, not spark-shell. So no `.show()` and it is not showing headers at least be default.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [show column names when doing query with spark-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56159734/show-column-names-when-doing-query-with-spark-sql)

Answer (score 0):

You should start the Spark SQL cli enabling it, using the config parameter `spark.hadoop.hive.cli.print.header`

Ex.

```bash
spark-sql --conf "spark.hadoop.hive.cli.print.header=true"
```