# show column names when doing query with spark-sql

Tags: apache-spark

I am using `spark-sql` to run sql, but it only shows result set,but doesn't show the corresponding columns names.

I would ask how to configure to show the columns name.

eg：

```
spark-sql>select a, b from c limit 1;
```

It shows

```
1 2
```

but I want to it to show:

```
a b
1 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the option that works for Apache Spark 2.1

```
spark-sql --master=yarn --hiveconf hive.cli.print.header=true
```

Answer (score 3):

Try initializing **`spark-sql`** cli with `spark.hadoop.hive.cli.print.header` conf as shown below..

```
$ spark-sql --conf "spark.hadoop.hive.cli.print.header=true"
```

**(or)**

Add the below property to **`/etc/spark2/conf/hive-site.xml`** file and restart the service.

```
<property>
    <name>hive.cli.print.header</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>
```

Refer to [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/196142/how-can-i-display-column-headings-in-spark-sql.html) link for more details regards similar requirement.

Comment: Thanks @Shu. I am using Spark 2.1，I have tried the approach you mentioned in the link ,but it doesn't work. Does it work for you?

Comment: @Tom,Sorry about that..I tried in `HDP2.6.5` and it worked..!

Comment: Thanks @Shu. Looks HDP provides this feature, and Apache Spark doesn't.